# How to change text of nodelist

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I use this code in the console:

```
document.querySelectorAll("a.pointer[title='Average']")
```

It returns  a list of Averages, each of which displays text on the page:

```html
<a class="pointer" title="Average" onclick="showScoretab(this)">421.95</a>
<a class="pointer" title="Average" onclick="showScoretab(this)">225.02</a>
<a class="pointer" title="Average" onclick="showScoretab(this)">292.51</a>
```

How would I go about changing the text of all of these to `"0"`? I've already tried:

```js
document.querySelectorAll("a.pointer[title='Average']").textContent = "0";
document.querySelectorAll("a.pointer[title='Average']").innerHTML = "0";
document.querySelectorAll("a.pointer[title='Average']").text = "0";
```

Comment: If you are using jQuery, why not just $("a.pointer[title='Average']").text("0");

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use loop for this purpose, for example using `for` loop :

```js
var links = document.querySelectorAll("a.pointer[title='Average']");

for (var i=0; i < links.length; i++) {
    links[i].innerHTML = '0';
}
```

```html
<a class="pointer" title="Average" onclick="showScoretab(this)">421.95</a><br>
<a class="pointer" title="Average" onclick="showScoretab(this)">225.02</a><br>
<a class="pointer" title="Average" onclick="showScoretab(this)">292.51</a>
```

**But since your using jQuery that could be simply like  :**

```
$("a.pointer[title='Average']").text('0');
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$("a.pointer[title='Average']").text('0');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a class="pointer" title="Average" onclick="showScoretab(this)">421.95</a>
<br>
<a class="pointer" title="Average" onclick="showScoretab(this)">225.02</a>
<br>
<a class="pointer" title="Average" onclick="showScoretab(this)">292.51</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

`document.querySelectorAll` returns a nodelist, not just a single object. Just iterate through each one and set the properties on each object:

```
var objects = document.querySelectorAll("a.pointer[title='Average']");
for (var i in objects) {
  object[i].innerHTML = "0";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Get the total `length` of the `<a class="pointer" title="Average" onclick="showScoretab(this)">` and do a `for` loop, and inside the loop, that's where you set the innerHTML of the elements into `0`

```js
var pointers = document.querySelectorAll("a.pointer[title='Average']");

for(var i = 0; i < pointers.length; i++){
  pointers[i].innerHTML = "0";
}
```

```html
<a class="pointer" title="Average" onclick="showScoretab(this)">421.95</a>
<a class="pointer" title="Average" onclick="showScoretab(this)">225.02</a>
<a class="pointer" title="Average" onclick="showScoretab(this)">292.51</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to visit each node in turn. The most backwards-compatible way to do this is via a simple `for` loop and `innerHTML`.

```js
var nodes = document.querySelectorAll("a.pointer[title='Average']");

for ( var i = 0; i < nodes.length; ++i )
  nodes[i].innerHTML = "0";
```

```html
<a class="pointer" title="Average" onclick="showScoretab(this)">421.95</a>
<a class="pointer" title="Average" onclick="showScoretab(this)">225.02</a>
<a class="pointer" title="Average" onclick="showScoretab(this)">292.51</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have jQuery as a tag to this question, I'm going to assume you are happy to use it.

```
$("a.pointer[title='Average']").text("0");
```

That should edit the text node directly.

https://jsfiddle.net/ddoticus/81wx7q4n/